# How to know if there is an error in stored procedure which have TRY CATCH handling in c# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, try-catch

Let me explain scenario: I have this code and stored procedure.

Case 1:

C# Code:

```
try 
{
     call uspMyProcedure using ado.net 
}
catch 
{
     Log exception 
}
```

Stored procedure

```
uspMyProcedure (*without try catch*)
```

This case 1, I can know if something error in stored procedure because exception comes to catch in C# code.

Case 2:

C# Code:

```
try 
{ 
    call uspMyProcedure using ado.net 
}
catch 
{
    Log exception 
}
```

Stored procedure

```
uspMyProcedure (*with try catch*)
```

This case 2, how can I know if something error in stored procedure because exception does not come to catch in C# code.

Thank you.

Mike

Comment: Is the try-catch in the stored procedure?

Comment: @MathewPaxinos Yes, if try-catch was in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN SQL Server you can re-throw the error in catch statement. Ex:-

*SQL Server 2012 or above*

```
BEGIN TRY  
.....
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH    
    PRINT 'In catch block.';  
    THROW;  
END CATCH;
```

*Older than SQL Server 2012*

```
BEGIN TRY
....
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max), @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = N'Error Number: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(5), ERROR_NUMBER()) + N'. ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(5), ERROR_LINE()), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
```

In SQL Server a reason for try - catch error handling is mainly to rollback transactions properly. after that you should throw the error so that the client applications will get to know about the error.

Comment: Many thanks for your explaination @Chamika. Well explained.

Comment: Hi @Chamika, I had tried already, THROW does not trow to client ( means not trowing to asp.net ).

Comment: Hi @Mike, I also tried out just now. But It is working for me (Error is getting captured in the client application). I have SQL Server 2016 installed in my pc. But I'm sure that the functionality is the same with 2012 and 2014 versions.

Comment: Hi @Chamika, Finally, THROW; working like charm. Thanks. (Thumbsup)

Answer (score 0):

We can get the all the possible SQL exception using:

```
SELECT * FROM sysmessages
```

and these exception can be handled in try catch block:

```
try
{
    //code
}
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{
        if (sqlEx.Message.StartsWith("Invalid object name"))
        {
            //code
        }
        else
            throw;
}
```

another way to know the possible error:

Execute and debug your stored procedure directly on sql-server, later you can handle all the possible exception in your try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mohit

Comment: Hi @Mohit, That is the point. If stored procedure used TRY CATCH, no exception will be thrown in .Net try catch. Is it right?